# Angular e2e test with Protractor: click intercepted by parent of element selected by id

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular2-testing, angular-e2e

Sometimes I get this error but not every time I run the test. What is causing this strange behavior?

> Failed: element click intercepted: Element `<div id="myButton">...</div>` is not clickable at point (616, 104). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="wrapper">...</div>`
>       (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.120)
>       (Driver info: chromedriver=77.0.3865.120 (416d6d8013e9adb6dd33b0c12e7614ff403d1a94-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#884}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-70-generic x86_64)

**file.html**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="myButton">Add</div>
</div>
```

**file.e2e-spec.ts**

```js
it('Example test', async () => {
  await element(by.id('myButton')).click();
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding an explicit wait?

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const button = element(by.id('myButton'));

await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button), 5000);
await button.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I do this check every time I need to click some element?

Comment: @Francesco well it depends on the element. With protractor you usually don't need to. But to prevent flakiness, I use a function where it waits for the element to be clickable, then clicks it (an element you pass as a parameter), and use that function everytime instead of doing the above for each element I want to click

Answer (score 1):

Finally I wrote a custum function that wait until the element is prensent and clickable before perform the click on it.

**util.ts**

```js
export const click = async (el: ElementFinder, time: number = 4000) => {
    await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), time);
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(el), time);
    return el.click();
};
```

**file.e2e-spec.ts**

```js
import * as pt_util from '../../util';
...

it('Example test', async () => {
  await pt_util.click(element(by.id('myButton')));
  ...
});
```